# problem: menu does not show in cocos2d layer

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone, layer

I am trying to add menu to a layer in cocos2d but it just does not appear. Here's the code which is written in init method of a layer

```
CCMenuItem *aButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"btnImg.png" selectedImage:@"btnImgSel.png" target:self selector:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
aButton.position = ccp(60.0,30.0);
CCMenu *aMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:aButton, nil];
aMenu.position = ccp(500.0,20);
[self addChild:aMenu];
```

Nothing is overlapping the position i specified for menu. Is anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like these:-

```
CCLayer *menuLayer1 = [[[CCLayer alloc] init]autorelease];
        [self addChild:menuLayer1];

CCMenuItemImage *startButton1 = [CCMenuItemImage
itemFromNormalImage:@"Play.png"
selectedImage:@"Play.png"                                             
 target:self
selector:@selector(Play:)];
 CCMenu *menu1 = [CCMenu menuWithItems: startButton1,nil];
    menu1.position = ccp(157,157 );
        [menu1 alignItemsVertically ];
        [menuLayer1 addChild: menu1];
```

Comment: i just copied and replaced the line "CCMenuItemImage...." and it's working :) perhaps there was some mistake in some character. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For those who are facing an irritating situation where the code is right but menu items are not showing then **check the image file**. I was using .png images and they were refusing to be displayed. There was something internally wrong with the file, so I replaced that file and it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the iPad your target platform? If so the "menu" should appear at the bottom of the screen. To display the Menu on iPhone adjust the "a.Menu.position" to anything lower than 480 in the first attribute of ccp

Comment: hi, it's iPad n i tried with CGPointZero position as well but application was simply getting halted at first line of creating menu item but now it's working. and thanks for telling about position issues in both platforms, i didn't know it before. :)